# Trying to run php file using "heroku run" and I get "bash permission denied"

Tags: php, bash, heroku, chmod

I'm trying to run a file with `heroku run path/to/file.php` and I get a reponse:

> bash: path/to/file.php: Permission denied

I've tried `chmod 755` on the file and directory, but it seems that heroku changes it back to 600... After running `chmod 755` it shows 755, but then when I exit bash and then come back the permissions are reset to 600.

What am I missing?

Also some people have suggested

```
heroku run php path/to/file.php
```

but I get an error saying

> bash: php: command not found

Comment: try heroku run "$(which php)" path/to/file.php

Comment: @SuperFamousGuy the result is `Running '/usr/bin/php path/file.php'` and then the response is `bash: /user/bin/php: No such file or directory` How is that possible?

Comment: That is quite bizarre. Try ls -la /user/bin/php and post the output

Comment: ls: cannot access /usr/bin/php: No such file or directory

Comment: wtf - when i do ls on the root that heroku bash puts me in there is no usr...

Comment: and `whereis php` returns php:

Comment: and your comment from below... there was no response. thx for the help!

Comment: BTW I can execute the file from the browser...

Comment: essentially the command below was trying to search your machine for the user that owns the file. No result means either that user doesn't exist, or there's no record of it on your machine.

whereis php returning php: means it doesn't know the location, and the fact that ls can't access the file leads me to believe that you have a problem with your installation.

What operating system are you using, and how did you install php?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to do.

- When creating the Heroku application, you have to make sure that the PHP buildpack is used. This is what will inject the PHP runtime into your application slug. Either add a `index.php` file (which is how PHP is detected) or hard-code it like this: `heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php.git`
- Set the library path as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614454/php-heroku-background-workers): heroku config:add LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/php/ext:/app/apache/lib
- Run your stuff: `heroku run ./php/bin/php --version`

To sum up:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php.git
heroku config:add LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/php/ext:/app/apache/lib
heroku run ./php/bin/php --version
```

A useful way to debug this is to bash into the running Heroku dyno: `heroku run bash`. That will let you poke around, see where things are at and experiment.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried running the command with [`sudo`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_sudo.htm) privileges:

```
sudo heroku run path/to/file.php
```

If your shell can't use the `php` command (i.e. its alias), you will need to provide the absolute path:

```
sudo /usr/bin/php path/to/file.php
```

That's where it's usually located. To find your PHP bin location, try:

```
whereis php
```

Comment: What happens if you execute all those commands using sudo? Are you sure you have sudo access?

Comment: Run ll on the file you're trying to run and tell us who the owner is.

Comment: Is the issue running sudo within heroku...? Not from my local... Sorry for rookie question i'm pretty new to heroku/cli

Comment: Sudo basically allows you run commands as the root user (it will override all file permissions). If you don't have sudo access, it will ask you for a password which you won't know. Some operating systems require you to have sudo privileges to do certain operations - apart from changing the file permissions to `777` you can't really do much else.

Comment: @SuperFamousGuy the owner is "u30214"... not sure what that means

Comment: The permissions being at 600 means only the owner of the file can execute. That means that even if you're root you're SOL, so figuring out what user actually owns the file is crucial.

Try running awk -v val=30214 -F ":" '$3==val{print $1}' /etc/passwd

Comment: `sudo heroku run [some cmd]` doesn't make sense here because you'd be running the `heroku` cli in `sudo` on your local machine instead of running `[some cmd]` on the Heroku runtime in `sudo`.